# Loop through javascript array to call API with delay

Tags: javascript

I have a script which calls [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md). I receive a response for specific symbol like `BTCUSDT`. API doesn't allow to call multiple symbols in API endpoint.
This string - `var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', function()` is a [node-schedule package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) which will call the script every hour at 00minutes(15:00/16:00/17:00...).

**FULLCODE**

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
 const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
 const schedule = require('node-schedule');
 var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
 const fetch = require("node-fetch");

 var today = new Date();
 var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
 var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
 var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

 var symbols = ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "ATOMBTC"];
 let cnt = 0;

 const callIt = () => {
     fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=1h&limit=1`)
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => {
             const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                 return {
                     Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                     High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                     Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                     Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                     Volume: parseFloat(d[5])
                 }
             });
             console.log(btcusdtdata);
             cnt++;
             if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000)
         })
         .catch((err) => {
             console.log(err);
         })

 };
 const j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', callIt)
```

Problem: This script call the properties inside an array one after another which is perfect for me. My problem is my node-schedule(`0 * * * *`)doesn't work.
I run the script and it's immediately send me the data. But I wan't to receive data only every hour and only after it call for properties in array. How I can insert a node-schedule function - `const j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', callIt)` inside a main function.
Everything works well, only that the script suppose to receive data every hour not immediately when I start it.

Comment: @mplungjan my bad, i'm sorry.

Comment: Please remove callIt() in your code, that was to test it
also replace `reject` with `console.log`

Comment: @mplungjan main question edited accordingly to your comment.

Comment: @mplungjan main question is edited. All errors are gone. Still the question in calling the properties in array one after another

Comment: What happens if you comment out `const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', callIt)`  and just have `callIt()` instead ?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm getting the BTCUSDT data( since its first in array) every 3 seconds. But I need to keep schedule to call the script every hour and then it's supposed to go through each array property with an interval of 3 seconds

Comment: I meant: DO you loop when you just call callIt -  I do not know how schedule works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215997/discussion-between-hexycode-and-mplungjan).

Comment: You still had my `callIt()` in your code. EITHER have `callIt()`  OR have `const j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', callIt)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do Ajax in an interval. Instead use setTimeout in a callback

something like this - note I added a reject in a catch() to see the error when you abuse the API:

the code here does not work at SO due to CORS issues

NOTE: `${symbols[cnt]}` is the trick

```js
const symbols = ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "ATOMBTC"];
let cnt = 0;


const callIt = () => {
  fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=1h&limit=1`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
          Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
          High: parseFloat(d[2]),
          Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
          Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
          Volume: parseFloat(d[5])
        }
      })
      console.log(btcusdtdata);
      cnt++;
      if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
};

// callIt(); // only to test without scheduler
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', callIt); // assuming this will call it first time
```

I wanted to destruct but failed. Still more elegant

```js
// https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h&limit=1

const data = [
  [1592215200000, "9147.70000000", "9150.00000000", "9107.00000000", "9114.93000000", "1335.61921100", 1592218799999, "12190574.36418155", 16160, "624.21625600", "5697793.49077209", "0"]
]
const d = data[0].slice(1,6);
const btcusdtdata = {};
["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"].forEach((name,i) => btcusdtdata[name]=+d[i]);
console.log(btcusdtdata)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it hits me up with an error - here `const callIt => `  SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration in =>

Comment: it's all fine thank you. Still I receive some dumb error again `Cannot access 'callIt' before initialization` I will upload full code in my main question.

Comment: that's another problem which appears now is exactly with data.map . Say's that `data.map is not a fucntion`

Comment: Then there is something wrong in the call. Perhaps you reached the limit when you tested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215990/discussion-between-hexycode-and-mplungjan).

Comment: @mrplungjan This one is not going to work since it's a wrong. The right one supposed to be this string -      `fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=' + symbols[cnt] + '&interval=1h&limit=1')`. Still setIntervals works well now, but my node-schedule 0 * * * * (means that script suppose to start working every hour) not getting started.

Comment: it is using a template string and should work just fine `\`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=1h&limit=1\``

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform tasks with fix amount of time in between, a `wait` function as shown below will come in handy:

```
const symbols = ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "ATOMBTC"];

function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  });
}

const j = schedule.scheduleJob("* * * * * *", function () {
  ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "ATOMBTC"].forEach((symbol, index) => {
    wait(2000 * index)
      .then(() =>
        fetch(
          `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${BTCUSDT}&interval=1h&limit=1`
        )
      )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(e => // do something with the error);
  });
});
```

If you want to perform async tasks one after another, `async/await` keywords can help you write cleaner code:

```
const symbols = ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "ATOMBTC"];

const j = schedule.scheduleJob("* * * * * *", async function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    try {
      const symbol = symbols[i];
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${BTCUSDT}&interval=1h&limit=1`
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      conosle.log(data);
    } catch (e) { // do something with the error }
  }
});
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to NOT run as an "interval" which is what your first code does. Mine only calls the next fetch if successful return. If you can, add a reject to the promise and a catch to the fetch

Comment: Personally I would use the second method (or other async flow control methods) instead of a fixed delay. The first method is only proposed in response to the goal of the question. Errors should always be caught somewhere depending on the desired result. Using `setTimeout` is not wrong if one understands the logic of the code and know what to expect,

Comment: I am not saying setTimeout is wrong. I use it in my own answer. I just recommend to stop if there are issues instead of hammering the server after being rejected

Comment: Got it. Your concern is totally valid and I agree that it should be taken into consideration, as a responsible developer.